# Critical Failure, need to reinstall

Tags: boot, grub2

I unfortunately in my naivety, destroyed my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installation on my HP pavilion laptop in one line involving the  "rm" command.

I can only access the GRUB command line by pressing F10 at start up, I have altered the BIOS settings to take precedence with booting from a USB, and saw this command while trying today:

`sudo dd if="ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso" of=/dev/sdX bs=8M`

So my question is, will the GRUB command line terminal recognize this, and how can I first determine the location of the USB that I have put in with the .iso file?

I can't describe how grateful I would be here I have tried quite a lot of things, but I never imagined I could damage my OS so badly like this

Comment: No, the grub command-line is limited and doesn't know the `dd`-command. You might be able to boot the iso-file via grub command-line. When booted you can use the session to create a bootable USB and use it to reinstall. Otherwise (and less complicated) use a different computer to create your installer.

Comment: Ok thanks so much, I have the latest iso on a USB stick downloaded from one of my others, what other steps do I need to create this installer you speak of?

Comment: Seems a working system is available, so use it to create installer from the iso-file. Use an appropriate tool to do that, for example `unetbootin` (Windows) or `usb-creator-gtk` (Ubuntu).

Comment: Yes one I am using now is fine with the exception of whatever occurred to allow that the person that did that horrible internal speaker trick to me this morning, thanks I will see how I go in my win10 and or Linux VMs on this machine